# How to batch unload data from Snowflake into S3?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to unload data from Snowflake automatically every week (preferably Sunday) into S3 as a batch-wise file with incremental data and not having duplicates from any previous files. Is this possible? I tried to find an unloading equivalent of Snowpipe but couldn't find any. But continuous load would not be ideal so I am looking for weekly exports to S3.

Do help me out as this is make-or-break to decide whether I should use Snowflake.

Comment: [COPY INTO location](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) for unloading and [tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html) for automation are places to start

Comment: Add Table Streams to Lukasz's list https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

Comment: With regards to duplicates, first make sure you have a primary key on the table, so you actually know what a duplicate is.